# Creating and setting custom attributes for Google Admin SDK

Tags: python, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client

I've been reading [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-schemas#set_fields) on how to update custom attributes for users. From how this is written, it seems as though I would be able to do the following:

```
    email = "a@a.com"
    results = service.users().list(domain="a.com",projection="full",query='email={0}'.format(email)).execute()

    if len(results["users"]) == 1:
        user = results["users"][0]
        user["customSchemas"]["TEST"] = "TEST"
        try:
            userResponse = service.users().update(userKey=email, body=user).execute()
        except HttpError, e:
            print(e)
```

However, I am thrown the error:

> https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/test%40test.com?alt=json
>   returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api">

I'm not sure if the error is because I am trying to update the fields incorrectly, if the escaping of the `@` in the url is causing issues, or if I don't have the proper scopes (I am using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.domain, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.userschema`).

How can I create custom attributes (for everyone) and update them for a user using the python SDK?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This has been a more accurate guide: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#instantiate_an_admin_sdk_directory_service_object

Comment: The link is generic to the Admin SDK usage and not to the operations that you asked in your original question.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest that you refer to the following documentation:

- [Create a Custom Schema](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-schemas#create_schema)
- [Set Custom Schema fields for a given user](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-schemas#set_fields)

Below you can find an example of how to create a custom schema and use it for users

```
# third parties imports
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# modify according to your requirements
CLIENT_SECRET = 'client.json'  # the credentials downloaded from the GCP Console
ADMIN_USER = 'admin@yourdomain.com'  # The admin user used by the service account
SCHEMA_USER = 'user@yourdomain.com'  # The user for which the custom schema will be set
SCHEMA_NAME = 'TestSchema'  # the name of the schema we want to work with

# Scopes
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.userschema',  # to create the schema
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user', ]  # to manage users

# service account initialization
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CLIENT_SECRET, scopes=SCOPES)
delegated_admin = credentials.create_delegated(ADMIN_USER)
admin_http_auth = delegated_admin.authorize(Http())

admin_sdk = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=admin_http_auth)  # Admin SDK service

# we list all the schemas...
schema_list_params = {
    'customerId': 'my_customer',
    'fields': 'schemas/schemaName',
}
schema_list = admin_sdk.schemas().list(**schema_list_params).execute()

# ... And we create a set with the names of the custom schemas
unique_schemas = set()
for schema in schema_list['schemas']:
    unique_schemas.add(schema['schemaName'])

# if the schema we want to work with is not there, we create it
if SCHEMA_NAME not in unique_schemas:
    schema_insert_params = {
        'customerId': 'my_customer',
        'body': {
            'schemaName': SCHEMA_NAME,
            'displayName': 'Test Schema',
            'fields': [
                {
                    'fieldName': 'TestField',
                    'fieldType': 'STRING',
                    'displayName': 'Test Field',
                    'multiValued': False,
                }
            ]
        },
    }
    schema_insert = admin_sdk.schemas().insert(**schema_insert_params).execute()

# we set a value for our custom schema on the desired user
user_patch_params = {
    'userKey': SCHEMA_USER,
    'body': {
        'customSchemas': {
            SCHEMA_NAME: {
                'TestField': 'My cool test value!'
            },
        },
    },
}
user_patch = admin_sdk.users().patch(**user_patch_params).execute()
```